Would you use befall or befell in this sentence?
I am writing a poem. Should it end with befall or befell to make it it grammatically correct? And do you think I could get away with keeping it as befall, even if it is not grammatically accurate, so long as the meaning it endeavours to convey is understood? It reads:

[You are in difficulties],
You know me, I will be your blanket, a shield against all,
I know you, who would the same, were it I, the same, befall

The last sentence should convey: you would do the same for me (be protective) if I got into difficulties.

If you mean is 'befall' worse than 'befell', no. Neither is clear, but maybe you want some high-toned ambiguity. Also, not sure a blanket is a shield as much as a comfort.

I would suggest rewriting the second line. It may not be a great second line for the one preceding it, which is good. Also, I personally find who would the same a little off-putting.

'' ... If it were I who experienced the same problem"

Sorry, I was trying not to criticize 'befall' as a forced rhyme. But nothing will befall on 'I', so I'd use 'me'.

@YosefBaskin Thanks for your reply.  I meant in terms of tense.  In the sentence I am essentially trying to say "you would do the same as me if the same thing that had happened to you, happened* to me".   *I guess one could read that as  had happened (befell) or was to happen to (befall).     Would anyone read the sentences and think in terms of tense and conclude that I should have used befell instead of befall, or is it not really an issue and the sentence adequately convey what I wanted it to, using befall? As for blanket, I am trying to indicate comfort as much as shield, if not more. Ta!

Thanks @user405662 for your feedback :-)

@EdwinAshworth Thanks for your reply.  Your answer would seem to indicate befell (the past tense of befall).  What is your view on the second part of my question?

Befall means happen to, so you need me rather than I.

If you rewrote the second line so it ended "to befall", you wouldn't have the problem with the tenses.

@KateBunting Thanks for your reply.  I am choosing to use I rather than me, as I am treating the poem as formal writing and I think it can be appropriate in that context to use I  after a linking verb such as were - though I can't be sure that is correct......  besides which, personally, I prefer the sound of I rather than me when reading the sentence out .  Thanks again.

@PeterShor  Thanks for your reply.  Your suggestion sounds very useful and I shall try it out.  I was wondering if it would ok to use "did befall" rather than "to"?  It just feels like a much better fit.....

That's almost certainly what it means.

You can achieve a pretty decent meter (and retain the rhyme) if you reword the second line as "I know you will be the same, if to me the same [should] befall." And this revised wording avoids the rather scattered syntax of the original.

Formal language makes grammatical errors less appropriate, not more.  I second Sven's and Greybeard's suggestion.


You know me, I will be your blanket, a shield against all,
I know you, who would the same, were it I, the same, befall

You know me, I will be your armour, a shield against all,
I know you would do the same, should to me the same befall.
